# import doesn't works?

Tags: python, unit-testing, import

i'm doing some unittest with python, and all was going ok, but i got a problem so weird, with a import i think, follow the problem:

i'm trying to create a object GlanceApi in my test, like another tests that i've done, but i got this error:

```
======================================================================
ERROR: setUpClass (__main__.TestGlance)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "glance_tests.py", line 22, in setUpClass
    self.glnce = glance.GlanceApi("")
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'GlanceApi'
```

and this is my code:

```
import unittest
import json
import time
import sys
sys.path.append("../src")
import glance
import novaapiclient

class TestGlance(unittest.TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(self):
        confFile = file('config.txt', 'r+w')
        configs = ""
        for line in confFile:
            if not (line.startswith('#')) and len(line) != 0:
                configs  = line.split(';')

        novaAPI = novaapiclient.NovaApiClient(str(configs[0]))
        novaAPI.make_auth(configs[1], configs[2], configs[3])

        self.glnce = glance.GlanceApi() # << HERE ERROR
        self.glnce.set_auth_obj(novaAPI.get_auth_obj())
```

It looks like another tests that i've done, but doesn't works to this case.
Thanks in advance.

This is the glance source:

```
import pycurl
import cStringIO
import os

class GlanceApi:

    def __init__(self):
        self.auth = ""
        self.http_handler = ""

    def set_auth_obj(self, authenticate):
        self.auth = authenticate


    def list_images(self, is_public=False, with_details=False):

        if self.auth.is_authed() == False:
            return False

        self.http_handler = pycurl.Curl()
        printer = cStringIO.StringIO()

        if with_details == False:
            url_complement = "/images"
        else:
            url_complement = "/images/detail"

        if is_public == False:
            full_url = str(self.auth.get_image_URL() + url_complement)
        else:
            full_url = str(self.auth.get_image_URL()[:30] + url_complement)

        headers = ["X-Auth-Token:%s" % str(self.auth.get_auth_token())]

        self.http_handler.setopt(pycurl.URL, full_url)
        self.http_handler.setopt(pycurl.HTTPGET, 1)
        self.http_handler.setopt(pycurl.HTTPHEADER, headers)
        self.http_handler.setopt(pycurl.WRITEFUNCTION, printer.write)
        self.http_handler.perform()

        http_code = int(self.http_handler.getinfo(pycurl.HTTP_CODE))
        self.http_handler.close()

        return printer.getvalue()


    def get_image_metadata(self, id, is_public=False):

        if self.auth.is_authed() == False:
            return False

        self.http_handler = pycurl.Curl()
        printer = cStringIO.StringIO()

        url_complement = "/images/%s" % id

        # Setting the request url according the is_public parameter.
        if is_public == False:
            full_url = str(self.auth.get_image_URL() + url_complement)
        else:
            full_url = str(self.auth.get_image_URL()[:30] + url_complement)

        headers = ["X-Auth-Token:%s" % str(self.auth.get_auth_token())]

        self.http_handler.setopt(pycurl.URL, full_url)
        self.http_handler.setopt(pycurl.CUSTOMREQUEST, 'HEAD')
        self.http_handler.setopt(pycurl.HTTPHEADER, headers)
        self.http_handler.setopt(pycurl.WRITEFUNCTION, printer.write)
        self.http_handler.perform()

        http_code = int(self.http_handler.getinfo(pycurl.HTTP_CODE))
        self.http_handler.close()

        return printer.getvalue()


    def add_image(self,  file_path, name, is_public=False):
        # Verifying if the user is authenticated.
        if self.auth.is_authed() == False:
            return False

        self.http_handler = pycurl.Curl()
        printer = cStringIO.StringIO()

        url_complement = "/images"

        if is_public == False:
            full_url = str(self.auth.get_image_URL() + url_complement)
        else:
            full_url = str(self.auth.get_image_URL()[:30] + url_complement)

        size = os.path.getsize(file_path)

        image = [(str(name), (pycurl.FORM_FILE, str(file_path)))]

        headers = ["X-Auth-Token:%s" % str(self.auth.get_auth_token()), "x-image-meta-name:%s" % name, "x-image-meta-size:%s" % str(size)]
        if is_public == True:
            headers.append("x-image-meta-is-public:true")

        self.http_handler.setopt(pycurl.URL, full_url)
        self.http_handler.setopt(self.http_handler.HTTPPOST, image)
        self.http_handler.setopt(pycurl.HTTPHEADER, headers)
        self.http_handler.setopt(pycurl.WRITEFUNCTION, printer.write)
        self.http_handler.perform()

        http_code = int(self.http_handler.getinfo(pycurl.HTTP_CODE))
        self.http_handler.close()

        return printer.getvalue()
```

this is the directory structure:

```
Project
   + src/
      - glance.py
      - ...
   + Tests/
      - glance_tests.py
      - ...
```

**EDIT**
RESOLVED, how? i've no idea, but i've done this, i create a new file named glanceapi.py, and copy the content the glance.py file, change the name at import and it works, i have no idea that what's the problem, could be some python bug, well, i want to say thanks to people that tried to help me.

Comment: Can you show your glance and GlanceApi code?

Comment: "glance" is the name of the python file and GlanceApi, is the name of the class inside the glance file.

Comment: @guisantogui Well, if that were the case, we wouldn't see this error. Post `glance.py` and let us see, otherwise, we won't be able to tell you what is wrong.

Comment: Is there a `glance.py` anywhere else?  What is the directory structure?  What is your `$PYTHONPATH`?

Comment: $PYTHONPATH? i'm not using it to another cases and it's working, i think that is not the problem.

Comment: @Lattyware This type of error can also happen with circular import problems where a module hasn't been fully loaded before it is called.  Though that doesn't seem to jibe too well with the fact that copy-pasting to a different file fixes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Go to IDLE, and see what the PYTHONPATH is.

```
import sys
sys.path
```

And if the place where Glance is located is not found in the path, I suppose you would have to insert/append it using sys.path.append(). Look at how to do your parameters and stuff here: http://effbot.org/librarybook/sys.htm

EDIT: Let me know if this does not work.